The AWS event bridge pipe with multiple enrichment steps
Is it possible to add more than one enrichment step before invoke  the target stage ?

EventBridge only supports one enrichment step before invoking the target.
However you can use workaround like lambda chaining where you can call a lambda function within a lambda and continue the chain as needed.
